# Angular4 project and Yarn

Tags: angular, yarnpkg

We trying to switch from npm to yarn. 
After yarn was installed:

```
yarn init
rm -rf node_modules
yarn
```

everything was just fine. 
But when I run npm start (ng serve) or npm test (ng test)
getting this error:

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'getSymbolByModule' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and update your "@angular/compiler-cli"

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on from the description in this post.
Did you try 
`yarn install`
first?